# ImportError: DLL load failed regarding sndlib / libsndfile

Tags: python, libsndfile

I am using Windows 7 64 bit.

I have these imports

```
from scikits.audiolab import Sndfile    
import numpy as NumpyObj
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import groupby
import heapq
import datetime        
import time
from math import sqrt as wurzel          
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans, vq
```

I installed all files for 64 bit if possible - including Python 2.6

I get this error message

```
"C:\Python26\python.exe"  skript.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "skript.py", line 4, in <module>
    from scikits.audiolab import Sndfile
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scikits\audiolab\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pysndfile import formatinfo, sndfile
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scikits\audiolab\pysndfile\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _sndfile import Sndfile, Format, available_file_formats, 
  ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

'Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.' is german for 'the specified module was not found'

What could be the reason? I used

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Python26\\Lib\\site-packages')
```

but no change.

There are a lot of threads but none of them deals with sndfile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to install http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/files/libsndfile-1.0.23-w64-setup.exe and copy libsndfile-1.dll to C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\scikits\audiolab\pysndfile (or add the path to 64 bit libsndfile-1.dll to the PATH environment variable).